# can not change the column name in DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas

Why I can not change the column name in DataFrame? I tried the following formula in python. Can anyone help me?

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'2019-04-01 00:00:00': 'xx'})
```

```
2019-04-01 00:00:00

c
f
g
```

Comment: print your column names to make sure that you are stating the correct name, ```df1.columns.tolist()```.

Comment: I did this. but it doesn't help

Comment: Perhaps the column is in datetime format, not string. Try: `df1 = df1.rename(columns={datetime.strptime('2019-04-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): 'xx'})`

Comment: It helped thanks . it it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment.

The column might be in `datetime` format, not `string`.

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns={datetime.strptime('2019-04-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): 'xx'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign a new name to a column or mulitple columns as follows:

`df.columns = ['xx']`

or if there are multiple columns

`df.columns = ['xx', 'yy']`

Answer (score 0):

The column name is not the exact same thing in this instance so when it is searching for '2019-04-01 00:00:00' it is not found and thus not changed. This could be because one is a string and the other is DateTime. Either make sure you have the type correct or try another method to rename the columns like so:

```
df1.columns = ['xx']
df1
```

This will require you to rename all columns so fixing the type is likely the way to go.